Proper use of variants with VT_RECORD and VT_BYREF
I need some better understanding of records stored in VARIANT.
If there is a VT_RECORD typed variant, it has the following structure (in 32-bit):
V->vt = VT_RECORD
V->DATA1 //(8 byte offset)  memory pointer to record's data (*void)
V->DATA2 //(12 byte offset) pointer to IRecordInfo interface (*IRecordInfo)

It seems when allocating the record, the IRecordInfo object is AddReffed
So when destroying the variant, it's necessary to release the IRecordInfo object as well.
But in case of BYREF variant?
In this case the variant is build in this way:
V->vt = VT_RECORD | VT_BYREF
V->DATA1 // -> pointer to a pointer of record's data (**void)
V->DATA2 //-> pointer to IRecordInfo interface (here experienced it is not (**IRecordInfo) but (*IRecordInfo))

What has to be done with the IRecordInfo pointer when allocating or deallocating a BYREF-ed record?
BYREF variants normally don't change any memory when used, they can be freed without dereferencing.
But here now I have a pointer to *IRecordInfo.
What is done by VariantClear, when it is freeing the BYREF variant?
Does it dereference the IRecordInfo object or not?
Experience welcomed!

See this alternative source code. I have no idea of the status of this code but from experience it mirrors COM's actual behaviour accurately.

A VT_BYREF variant is just a pointer away, you can use a macro like this one to dereference it and than work with it normally https://pastebin.com/raw/KdbuAaqJ

IRecordInfo merely describes the structure of the record, it says nothing about where it is stored.  Necessary because you don't know the #pragma pack directive that was used in the server.  Typically 4 or 8, mostly 8 btw.  So it doesn't matter whether it is VT_BYREF or not, treat it like any COM interface pointer and Release() when you no longer need it.

@user207421 interesting, in your code VARIANTS of type VT_RECORD|VT_BYREF seem to be handled like not referenced VT_RECORD.
else if (V_VT(pSrc) == (VT_RECORD|VT_BYREF))
{
hres = VARIANT_CopyIRecordInfo(pvargDest, pvargSrc);
}
If you have a VT_BYREF|VT_I4 you will have a pointer saved to the 4 byte data (indirect)
Need more documentation for it

The support for VARIANTS of MS is really ugly. They defined many VARTYPES like VT_CLSID, VT_PTR i.e. and are not giving anything about their use in direct and indirect.
They give functions like VarAdd, VarSub etc. but these functions don't support BYREF variants. It seems they have stopped everything with the dead of classic VB. It seems to be evil for them to complete the support for VARIANTS. It is indeed only a common use data structure for direct access of memory. This is not a bad thing.

You don't have to make any distinction in your code betwen byref & byval once you have dereferenced a VARIANT. PS: not all types are ok for VARIANT, VT_CLSID and VT_PTR are for example not valid for a VARIANT struct see the table here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum#remarks
